# How to store different parts of a text file into different variables?

Tags: java, textfield, buffered

I am trying to read parts of a text file with the format

```
John Smith
72
160
```

The first line being the name (string), and the second and third lines being height and weight (both ints). However, I cannot find a way to store each of these into their own variables, instead I can only figure out how to store the whole thing into one variable and print it. This is the code that I have as of now

```
        try
    {
        File file = new File("person.txt");
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
               stringBuffer.append(line);
               stringBuffer.append("\n");
            }
        fileReader.close();
        System.out.println(stringBuffer);
    }
```

In this part

```
stringBuffer.append(line);
stringBuffer.append("\n");
```

I was thinking of trying to add a part in the middle of both those lines that stored a variable, but it did not seem possible. I also thought of using a for loop and using that to my advantage somehow, but could not figure out a way to do it with that either.

Is there any possible way to do this that I do not know about? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading and parsing a text file in Java has been getting easier in every new version. You can try the following way:

```
List<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("person.txt")).collect(Collectors.toList());
String name = lines.get(0);
Integer height = Integer.parseInt(lines.get(1));
Integer weight = Integer.parseInt(lines.get(2));
```

Comment: When I try this, the "List", "Files", "Paths", and "Collectors" are all underlined in red because they havent been initialized. Do I have to initialize these (and if so how?) or do something else?

Comment: @msh118, you need to import those classes / interfaces. If you are using Eclipse, just do Ctrl + Shift + O.

Comment: @msh118, Glad to be of help

Answer (score -1):

```
    File file = new File("person.txt");
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

    String firstline = bufferedReader.readLine();
    String secondline = bufferedReader.readLine();
    String thirdline = bufferedReader.readLine();

    fileReader.close();
```

Comment: Code dump answers are not helpful to future visitors. Please at least *explain* your answer and your code. Tell why you recommend doing what you're doing.

Comment: This didnt work when I tried to test it by printing after the third line initialization :/ Is there something I may be doing wrong with that?

Comment: The file should have 3 lines